# Отпричастное и отглагольное прилагательные в краткой форме

Tags: краткое-прилагательное, краткое-причастие

Как известно, в краткой форме прилагательное может иметь приставку и тем не менее оставаться прилагательным (сдержанн, взволнованн). Это отпричастные прилагательные, пишущиеся с удвоенным "нн". В отглагольных же прилагательных в краткой форме содержится одно "н": писан, непоен. Отсюда вытекает важность в определении словообразования.

Вопрос:
Существуют ли отглагольные прилагательные, имеющие приставку, и существуют ли отпричастные прилагательные, не имеющие приставки? И как все-таки отделить отпричастное от отглагольного?

Answer (score 1):

В школьной программе отглагольные прилагательные не отличают от отпричастных, там отличают **отглагольные прилагательные от причастий**. Однако в науке такое отличие существует.

**Отглагольные прилагательные**:

> 1) ***Прилагательные, образованные от глагольной основы суффиксальным
>   способом, сохраняющие только генетическую связь с глаголами.***
>   Дубильный, копировальный, купальный, обручальный, сушильный, точильный
>   (**с суффиксом -льн-ый)**. Восклицательный, гадательный, желательный,
>   избирательный, изобретательный, наблюдательный, одобрительный,
>   оскорбительный, прохладительный, раздражительный, употребительный (с
>   **суффиксом -тельн-ый)**. Бывалый, вялый, горелый, запоздалый, зрелый,
>   обледенелый, окаменелый, оцепенелый, полинялый, прелый, спелый (**с
>   суффиксом -л-ый, восходят к древнерусским причастиям)**. Висячий,
>   горючий, гремучий, кипучий, колючий, лежачий, летучий, стоячий,
>   сыпучий, ходячий **(с суффиксами -ач- (-яч-), -уч- (-юч-), восходят к
>   древнерусским причастиям**).

2) Отпричастные прилагательные:

> ***т. е. причастия, утратившие видо-временное и залоговое значения, а
>   также  глагольное управление (адъективированные причастия).*** Вареный,
>   граненый, дареный, драный, жареный, званый, мороженый, раненый,
>   рваный, соленый, сушеный (**с суффиксами -и-, -ен-**). Взволнованный,
>   желанный, изысканный, истощенный, квалифицированный, преданный,
>   растерянный, сдержанный, уверенный, умеренный, усиленный (**с суффиксами
>   -ни-, -енн-**). Допустимый, заменимый, излечимый, ископаемый, невыносимый, недосягаемый, неизгладимый, неподражаемый, непромокаемый,
>   несгораемый, неувядаемый, осязаемый (**с суффиксами -м-, -ем-)**.
>   Блестящий, вызывающий, животрепещущий, многозначащий, начинающий,
>   подходящий, потрясающий, приходящий, сверкающий, угрожающий (**с
>   суффиксами -ущ-(-ющ-), -ащ- (ящ-), иногда сложные образования).**
>   Падший, прошедший (**с суффиксом -ш-**). Избитый (оборот речи),
>   надтреснутый (голос), отпетый (негодяй), смятый (костюм), сплюснутый
>   (нос), спертый (воздух) и т. п. (**с суффиксом -т-**).

https://how-to-all.com/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5:%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Приведённые Вами прилагательные взволнованный (голос), сдержанный (человек, характер), писаный (красавец) - отпричастные прилагательные, т.е. бывшие причастия, превратившиеся в прилагательные

```
  в краткой форме прилагательное может иметь
  приставку и тем не менее оставаться 
  прилагательным(сдержанн, взволнованн). Это 
 отпричастные прилагательные, пишущиеся с удвоенным 
 "нн". В отглагольных же прилагательных в краткой форме 
  содержится одно "н": писан, непоен.
```

Сдержанна, взволнованна, но: сдержан, взволнован.

В  кратких прилагательных пишется **столько НН, сколько в полной форме**: сдержанная девушка (в мужском роде одно Н  ), в кратких же причастиях - всегда одно Н: девушка (какова?) сдержанна, характер (каков?) сдержан - прилагательное // клятва (что сделана?) сдержана бойцами, слово им (что сделано?) сдержано - причастие.

Как отличить прилагательное от причастия?

1) Отглагольные прилагательные образуются только от глаголов несовершенного вида: кипяченое молоко от кипятить, жженая пробка от жечь.

Но есть целый ряд отглагольных прилагательных-исключений: деланный, жеманный, виденный, желанный, чванный, чеканный, окаянный, медленный, священный, невиданный, неслыханный, нежданный, негаданный, нечаянный, считанный, недреманное око.

Если же форма образована от глагола совершенного вида, то это причастие: решенная задача от решить, брошенные вещи от бросить. Исключения: смышленый, названый — с одним н.

2) У отглагольных прилагательных нет приставок: жареная котлета, путаный ответ. Если к прилагательному прибавляется приставка не-, то оно остается прилагательным и пишется с одним н: гашеная известь — негашеная известь; глаженое белье — неглаженое белье.

У причастий могут быть приставки: поджаренное мясо, запутанные следы.

3) У отглагольных прилагательных нет зависимых слов: сушеные грибы, квашеная капуста. У причастий могут быть зависимые слова: сушенные на солнце грибы, квашенная на зиму капуста.

4) Отглагольные слова на -ованный, -еванный — прилагательные, они всегда пишутся с двумя н (прессованный, корчеванный).

Прилагательные кованый, жеваный, пишутся с одним н, так как -ов и -ев входят в корень, в чем убеждаемся, разобрав слова по составу.

Следовательно, если мы рассматриваем форму, образованную от глагола, которая не имеет приставки или зависимого слова, то прежде чем решить, причастие это или прилагательное, следует определить вид глагола, от которого эта форма образована.

Полезно сопоставить смешиваемые формы:

масляные (краски) — прилагательное, образованное от существительного масло с помощью суффикса -ян;

масленый (блин) — отглагольное прилагательное, образованное от глагола маслить; замасленный (фартук) — причастие, образованное от глагола замаслить.

Подробнее о правилах написания Н/НН: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/29.htm

Comment: В справке, приведенной вами вначале, содержатся сведения о том, что суффиксы "н" и "ен" имеют отпричастные прилагательные. Позже вы называете их "отглагольными" (при пояснении удвоений). Почему?

Comment: Потому что термин "отпричастные прилагательные" узкоспециальный, употребляется в научной среде высшей школы, а справочники ориентированы на школьников и просто любознательных граждан, в этой среде все образования, имеющие глагольное происхождение, делятся на причастия, отглагольные прилагательные, отглагольные существительные (тушёнка - тушёный). Если причастие теряет активные  глагольные признаки, оно превращается в отглагольное прилагательное, хотя по сути это отпричастное прилагательное, ведь произошла адъективизация причастия, а не глагола.

Comment: В ряде случаев даже если у глагола есть приставка, он совершенного вида, слово является прилагательным. К примеру, в краткой форме. И это влияет на написание суффикса. По каким критериям отличать отпричастные прилагательные и причастия в краткой форме, с приставкой?

Comment: Облака (что сделаны?) - рассеяны ветром (их рассеял ветер)-причастие, в кратком причастии пишется одна -Н- . Дети (каковы?)  рассеянны  т.е невнимательны ) - их никто не рассеивал, это их качество, можно заменить другим прилагат., значит, это краткое прилагат., там столько - н-, сколько в полной форме (рассеянный - рассеянны). Реки (что сделаны?) скованы льдом - причастие - их сковал лёд. Движения (каковы?) скованны (неловки, тяжелы) - их никто не сковывал, это их качество. Чаши весов не уравновешены (их не уравновесили) - больная неуравновешенна (нельзя сказать, что её кто-то не уравновесил)

Comment: Причастие - признак по действию,  от которого  можно задать вопрос сделан  кем? чем? и перестроить в сочетание который + глагол, прилагательное - постоянный признак, качество, состояние- нельзя задать вопрос кем? чем? и нельзя вернуть в глагол, но можно заменить синонимичным прилагательным, они часто и даются  в сочетаниях с другими прилагательными: женщина ровна, сдержанна (сама по себе, её никто не сдерживал, нельзя сказать сдержана кем?)